Cloudformation resource expects different ID
My cloudformation nested stack failes because some resource cannot be found

Resource handler returned message: "function id
klgmrt6o3zf7fcrdlnptvfi3su not found (Service: AppSync, Status Code:
404, Request ID: 0f33da66-d7ca-4922-a716-c0f76b845ae3)" (RequestToken:
195fb906-2889-282e-c3c0-237ef6a87c17, HandlerErrorCode: NotFound)


I have checked this resource, it exists but it has a different ID then klgmrt6o3zf7fcrdlnptvfi3su.
So the question is, how to i fix this issue?
For the context i dont need this resource anyway but i cannot deploy my app because its stucked
